# Прогон в foreach с изменением количества элементов

Tags: c#, многопоточность, циклы, foreach, parallel

У меня есть список. Необходимо прогнать все его элементы, вызвать в каждой итерации функцию расчета и при каком-то условии, удалить элемент из цикла и продолжить итерации.

Вначале думал про for и если удаляем, делать i--, т.к. уменьшилось количество элементов на 1, но это не сделать при параллельном прогоне, поэтому думаю сделать подобное в foreach, чтобы не привязываться к индексу элемента. Но при изменение foreach выскакивает исключение, что логично.

Можно ли как-нибудь прогнать параллельно по циклу и по условию, если что удалить элемент. Чтобы это не сказывалась на других элементах в параллельных потоках?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если удалять элемент из коллекции сразу же на месте не требуется — заведите еще одну (потокобезопасную) коллекцию, элементы подлежащие удалению складывайте в нее, после завершения первого цикла просто удалите из первой коллекции все элементы, присутствующие во второй:

```
// заводим коллекцию
var forRemoving = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    ...
    // складываем в нее элементы подлежащие удалению
    forRemoving.Add(item);
}
// удаляем
foreach (var item in forRemoving)
    items.Remove(item);
```

---

Если для вашей задачи не принципиально удаление элементов из входной коллекции, а подойдет также вариант с формированием новой коллекцией — можно воспользоваться функционалом Parallel Linq:

```
var result = items.AsParallel()
                  .Where(item => condition(item))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, весьма признателен!

Comment: Зачем нужен `AsParallel`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, у автора параллельная обработка, видимо вычисление `condition(item)` трудоемкое. Уж не знаю как это у него реализовано - может быть через `Parallel.For`, вот я ему и предлагаю вариант с использованием PLINQ

Answer (score 1):

> У меня есть список.

Если список - это именно `List<Smth>`, то используй обычный цикл `for`.

Обращаю внимание, что удаление нескольких элементов через `Remove` неэффективно, поскольку приведёт к квадратичной асимптотике (хвост всё время сдвигается). Правильным вариантом было бы использовать метод [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx). Ну либо написать обраотку списка в один проход с ручным сдвигом конца по мере порверки.